# How do I chain multiple conditions in a Vue JS v-if conditonal?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, if-statement

I am trying to only show results that match several countries. I must have the syntax wrong and I have tried various different ways. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

````
<div class="person" v-for='user in users' v-if="user.country === 'United States || user.country === Japan'">
        <span>{{ user.first_name }}, {{ user.last_name }}</span>
        <a :href="'mailto:' + user.email | lowercase">{{ user.email }}</a>
        <span>{{ user.country }}</span>
      </div>
    ```
````

Comment: why you don't use a computed property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error - an unclosed quote, the fix is:

```
v-if="user.country === 'United States' || user.country === 'Japan'"
```

But the Vue3 docs say:

> It's not recommended to use v-if and v-for on the same element due to implicit precedence. Refer to style guide for details.

so you should probably do:

```
<template v-for="user in users">
<div class="person" v-if="user.country === 'United States' || user.country === 'Japan'">
        <span>{{ user.first_name }}, {{ user.last_name }}</span>
        <a :href="'mailto:' + user.email | lowercase">{{ user.email }}</a>
        <span>{{ user.country }}</span>
      </div>
</template>
```

But my preferred way is to use a computed:

```
<script setup>
...
const filteredUsers = computed(() => users.filter(user => ['United States', 'Japan'].includes(user.country)));
...
</script>
<template>
<div class="person" v-for="user in filteredUsers">
        <span>{{ user.first_name }}, {{ user.last_name }}</span>
        <a :href="'mailto:' + user.email | lowercase">{{ user.email }}</a>
        <span>{{ user.country }}</span>
      </div>
</template
```